# Jello Shots Techniques: Alcohol Concentration

Tags: alcohol, gelatin, cocktails

When making jello shots, what proportions do you typically use?

For hard liquor like Gin, Tequila or Vodka, I've been using 1 part hot water to dissolve the jello and then 1 part cold spirits.  Some of these seem stronger than others.

For a liqueur like Pama (only 17%), it froze in the freezer and I had to wait for it to thaw.  I used 1 part cold Pama, but the general consensus was that the shot needed to be stronger.

The Jello seems to gel just fine.

Comment: This is really close to being off-topic for being a mixed-drink question. On the other hand, gelatin use is highly on-topic! I'm inclined to vote to close this one, but recommend rephrasing it as something like "How does alcohol affect gel proportions?" and asking about gelatin vs agar vs etc, etc. Rather than jello shots. :)

Comment: I voted to close, but I wouldn't have voted if the question was rephrased to something like Harlan suggested.

Comment: It's edible and it involves preparation, not brewing. I think the Prohibition Posse should relax a bit.

Comment: What's wrong with mixed drink questions?

Comment: @Brendan: A subset of the community thinks they should be banned. See: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/121/are-questions-on-alcohol-beverages-allowed/151#151

Comment: This question is really well-worded and specific. I think a knowledge of alcohol concentration in a jello shot will only improve my wherewithal as a cook. I would vote anti-close.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably fine with the 1:1 ratio for your likely 80 proof liquors.  For weaker liqueurs just add more.  You probably want 2:1 if you can get it to work.